# Stored Procedure with if statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure which is supposed to check whether a field is empty and execute one query, otherwise execute another but I'm getting an error. Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE mw_info(
    m_date_begin INTEGER,
    m_date_end INTEGER,
    m_from INTEGER,
    m_numberOfrecords INTEGER,
    m_callsource VARCHAR(15))
 BEGIN

    IF (m_callsource = '') THEN

       SELECT * 
         FROM mw_iaa 
        WHERE calllegcode IN ('CB_A','CB_B')
          AND calltime BETWEEN m_date_begin AND m_date_end
        ORDER BY calltime DESC 
        LIMIT m_from, m_numberOfrecords;

    ELSE     

       SELECT * 
         FROM mw_iaa 
        WHERE calllegcode IN ( 'CB_A', 'CB_B')
          AND callsource = m_callsource
          AND calltime BETWEEN m_date_begin AND m_date_end
        ORDER BY calltime DESC 
        LIMIT m_from, m_numberOfrecords;    

    END IF; 

 END;  
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And this is the error:

> Error Code : 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'else
>     SELECT * FROM mw_iaa WHERE calllegcode' at line 1

What can the problem be?

Comment: Hi when posting code please highlight it and click the `{}` button or use ctrl + k to mark it up as I've done here. It'd be nice if your code was formatted in a more readable format; your indentation makes this difficult to read (I've changed this).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in only one query, and get rid of the `IF` statement like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mw_iaa
WHERE ((m_callsource = '') OR (callsource = m_callsource))
  AND calllegcode IN ('CB_A', 'CB_B')
  AND callsource = m_callsource
  AND calltime BETWEEN m_date_begin AND m_date_end
ORDER BY calltime DESC 
LIMIT m_from, m_numberOfrecords;
```

Then, whenever you pass the `m_callsource` parameter with `''`, the condition `((m_callsource = '') OR (callsource = m_callsource))` will be ignored as it was not presented.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen errors like this then I've had tab characters in the procedure source.

Try replacing all tab chars with spaces.